# docker selenium stand alone chrome or firefox issue, org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver

OS:windows7

Docker image: docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/standalone-chrome:4.0.0-alpha-6-20200730

I am trying to run the following code, throwing the following error:

java - selenium

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        
        URL url = null;
        try {
             url= new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    WebDriver driver=new RemoteWebDriver(url,DesiredCapabilities.chrome());
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
           System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        Assert.assertEquals(driver.getTitle(), "Google");
        driver.quit();
    }
```

error:Aug 03, 2020 1:25:11 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities chrome
INFO: Using `new ChromeOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()`
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'BALAJI-PC', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_231'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:573)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
at com.init.Google_TC.main(Google_TC.java:26)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:4444
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:247)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:165)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient.execute(OkHttpClient.java:103)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:105)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
... 4 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606)
at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:129)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:245)
... 26 more